# I need to add caption on this slide show on wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, slide

Please i need to find a solution to add caption to this slide show , i try post id thumb but it shows the caption of featured image , i need the captions of the images that r on slide

the code of the slide :

```
<?php
                                        global $wpdb, $post;

                                        $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'lioit_slideshow_imgs', false);
                                        if (!is_array($meta)) $meta = (array) $meta;
                                        if (!empty($meta)) {
                                        $meta = implode(',', $meta);
                                        $images = $wpdb->get_col("
                                        SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts
                                        WHERE post_type = 'attachment'
                                        AND ID in ($meta)
                                        ORDER BY menu_order ASC LIMIT 15
                                        ");

                                        foreach ($images as $att) {
                                        // get image's source based on size, can be 'thumbnail', 'medium', 'large', 'full' or registed post thumbnails sizes
                                        $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src($att, 'full');
                                        $src = $src[0];

                                        ?>
                                <img src="<?php echo $src; ?>" alt=""  >



                                <?php  }
                                        } ?>
```

Comment: I've never heard about the "lioit slider". You should provide the code so I can check whether the caption is saved in the database or not. If it's not saved in the database, then you cannot retrieve it. Also consider using the WP Meta Slider (https://wordpress.org/plugins/ml-slider/). It has support for multiple slider libraries and it's fully customizable.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to retrieve the "alternative text", the "image title" and other Wordpress Image native fields, then the following code will help you.

If you're looking to retrieve "custom fields" from the database, then there's a different approach and you need to provide more details about the plugin you're using.

Code:

```
<?php
global $wpdb, $post;

$meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'lioit_slideshow_imgs', false);
if(!is_array($meta)) $meta = (array) $meta;
if(!empty($meta)){
    $meta = implode(',', $meta);
    $images = $wpdb->get_col("
        SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts
        WHERE post_type = 'attachment'
        AND ID in ($meta)
        ORDER BY menu_order ASC LIMIT 15
    ");
    foreach($images as $att){
        // get image's source based on size, can be 'thumbnail', 'medium', 'large', 'full' or registed post thumbnails sizes
        $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src($att, 'full');
        $src = $src[0];
        $alt = get_post_meta($att, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
        $image_title = $att->post_title;
        $caption = $att->post_excerpt;
        $description = $att->post_content;
        echo '<img src="' . $src . '" alt="' . $alt . '" />';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Yep because you need to display "$caption", "$description", "$alt", "$image_title" or "$description" on the screen. You can use `<div><?php echo $caption; ?></div>`. You'll have to position the element by yourself. It's beyond this question's scope.

Comment: i tried it but it show the caption of featured image of the post